# Magento2 override Newsletter Model showing error

Tags: magento2, error, newsletter, override-model

I want to do some modifications inside Subscriber.php model file inside Newsletter module with mentioned below 2 methods, so i have override model with my custom module with di.xml with following code:

```
<preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber" type="Commercepundit\Dealerregistration\Model\Subscriber" />
```

Here is my Subscriber.php code:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @category Commercepundit
 * @package  Commercepundit_Dealerregistration
 * @module   Dealerregistration
 * @author   Commercepundit Developer
*/
namespace Commercepundit\Dealerregistration\Model;

/*use Commercepundit\Core\Helper\Data as CoreHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;*/

class Subscriber extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber
{

    public function __construct(
        \Commercepundit\Core\Helper\Data $coreHelper
    )
    {
        $this->coreHelper = $coreHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Sends out confirmation email
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function sendConfirmationRequestEmail()
    {
        if ($this->getImportMode()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ) || !$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            ]
        )->setTemplateVars(
            ['subscriber' => $this, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()]
        )->setFrom(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->addTo(
            $this->getEmail(),
            $this->getName()
        );
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Sends out confirmation success email
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        if ($this->getImportMode()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ) || !$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            ]
        )->setTemplateVars(
            ['subscriber' => $this]
        )->setFrom(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->addTo(
            $this->getEmail(),
            $this->getName()
        );
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        return $this;
    }

}
```

When i run this code, i am getting following error:
**There was a problem with the subscription: The resource isn't set.**

Can anyone let me know what could be missing?

Comment: Its working fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try:** please remove the generated folder and cleaned cache after replacing a code

```
<?php

namespace Commercepundit\Dealerregistration\Model;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;

class Subscriber extends \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber
{

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Newsletter\Helper\Data $newsletterData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = [],
        DateTime $dateTime = null,
        \Commercepundit\Core\Helper\Data $coreHelper
    ) {
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(DateTime::class);
        $this->coreHelper = $coreHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $newsletterData, $scopeConfig, $transportBuilder, $storeManager, $customerSession, $customerRepository,  $customerAccountManagement, $inlineTranslation, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data, $dateTime);
    }

    /**
     * Sends out confirmation email
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function sendConfirmationRequestEmail()
    {
        if ($this->getImportMode()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ) || !$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            ]
        )->setTemplateVars(
            ['subscriber' => $this, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()]
        )->setFrom(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->addTo(
            $this->getEmail(),
            $this->getName()
        );
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Sends out confirmation success email
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        if ($this->getImportMode()) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        ) || !$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
        ) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->setTemplateOptions(
            [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            ]
        )->setTemplateVars(
            ['subscriber' => $this]
        )->setFrom(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->addTo(
            $this->getEmail(),
            $this->getName()
        );
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your construct with below code and try:
please remove generated folder and cleand cache after replacing code

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
    \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
    \Commercepundit\Core\Helper\Data $coreHelper
) {
    $this->_date = $date;
    $this->mathRandom = $mathRandom;
    $this->coreHelper = $coreHelper;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have removed construct and used scope config to get system configuration value so my purpose was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add below file in your __construct method with variable like below:

`protected $_transportBuilder;
 public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
) {
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
}`

and then remove generated and var directory.